# Failed to start Cryptography Setup for 0

Tags: centos, cryptsetup

What does it mean?
What should I do to fix it?

```
[root@MYSRV /]# systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@0.service
● systemd-cryptsetup@0.service - Cryptography Setup for 0
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/crypttab; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-01-20 22:00:05 UTC; 4min 19s ago
     Docs: man:crypttab(5)
           man:systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8)
           man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
  Process: 3176 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 0 2 * * (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 3176 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 20 22:00:05 MYSRV systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for 0...
Jan 20 22:00:05 MYSRV systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@0.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 20 22:00:05 MYSRV systemd[1]: Failed to start Cryptography Setup for 0.
Jan 20 22:00:05 MYSRV systemd[1]: Unit systemd-cryptsetup@0.service entered failed state.
Jan 20 22:00:05 MYSRV systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@0.service failed.
```

Comment: What is your `/etc/crypttab`.  You have one right?  `systemd-cryptsetup` is generated by `systemd-cryptsetup-generator` based on the contents of `/etc/crypttab`.

Comment: It has only single line... most likely added by gitlab-omnibus package: "0 2 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create CRON=1"

Comment: That looks to be an fstab line in reverse.  A crypttab has similar syntax to /etc/fstab but does not have mount/fsck numbers (what appear to be at the beginning of your crypttab).  A sesnsible crypttab should look something like [the example at arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab)

Comment: Then I think it was by mistake added to crypttab instead of crontab. I simply need to move it in crontab. Thanks.

Comment: You should add a self answer.  First paste your old crypttab and the example from the wiki. And explain that `systemd-crytpsetup` do read the crypttab.  It may prove useful to others.